# Use jQuery to Add and Then Remove (and Then Add) a Stylesheet on Successive Clicks

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

I am attempting to create a button that will change the font on a website.  Essentially, I just need the button to check if the stylesheet exists, and then remove it if it does or add it if it does not upon being clicked.

Here is the code I am currently using (which results in the stylesheet being added and then readded upon successive clicks):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (jQuery('#opendyslexic').length) {
    jQuery('#opendyslexic-toggler').click(function() {
            jQuery('#opendyslexic').remove();
    });
}
else {
    jQuery('#opendyslexic-toggler').click(function() {
        jQuery('<link rel ="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/wp-content/css/opendyslexic.css" type="text/css" id="opendyslexic">').appendTo("head");
    });
};
</script>
```

So, the code is working insofar as adding the stylesheet is concerned, but it does not remove the stylesheet as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are binding multiple events on every button click. Instead have only a single click event.

Also you would need set the disabled property of the stylesheet as the styles are still in memory. That would be a better idea instead of removing and adding it.

```
jQuery('#opendyslexic-toggler').click(function() {
     var $styleSheet = jQuery('#opendyslexic');

     $styleSheet.prop('disabled') ?  $styleSheet.prop('disabled', false)  
                                  : $styleSheet.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: That is a much more elegant way of achieving the objective.  Thank you.

Comment: @Zyniker.. glad to have helped :)